How to merge video stream from one file and audio streams from another one?
Situation:
I did encoded a h.264 input_original.mkv file to h.265 output_hevc.mkv
After long encoding process I realise there are wrong audio streams was choose.
I need to get new output_hevc_2.mkv which would based on
copy of video stream from output_hevc.mkv and maped audio streams from input_original.mkv
Is that technically possible?
P.s. I've seen this link
ffmpeg-adding-re-encoding-audio-stream-on-video-file
It's not the same question because it'll generate new output file with video stream from input_original.mkv.

Check FFmpeg map option. Syntax without re-encoding: ffmpeg -i input0.mkv -i input1.mkv -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.mkv

Thank you, question is solved, ffmpeg even much more powerful than I imagined

In case of you need to specify a/v/s streams
ffmpeg -hide_banner \
-i "input_0.mkv" \
-i "input_1.mkv" \
-map 0:v:0  \
-map 1:a:0  \
-map 1:a:4  \
-map 0:s:0  \
-map 0:s:2  \
-c copy \
"result_output.mkv"

This will merge video stream from input_0.mkv and selected audio and subtitle streams from input_1.mkv to result_output.mkv
